# Initializing static variables in ue4 c++

Tags: c++, static, unreal-engine4, static-variables

I have a actor class `ANodeBase`. Each node must have a unique `id`. To realize that, i create static variable `id_counter`.

Code:

```
//ANodeBase.h
static int id_counter;
//ANodeBase.cpp
#include "NodeBase.h"

int ANodeBase::id_counter = 0;

ANodeBase::ANodeBase()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = false;
    id = id_counter;
    id_counter++;//the only change to a variable in the project
}
```

Problem is that `id_counter` wasn't initialized, more precisely, it is initialized by 13, even if I restart ue4, even when I add some code and recompile project. When I create other actors, they increase be 1.

If it important, object directly created in the engine is `BP_NodePC : NodePC : NodeBase : Actor`

Can someone explain why does it happen or suggest an alternative count.

**EDIT:** For some unknown reason, unreal create 12 objects before launch. Don't know how fix that and why it happening

Comment: Is `static int id_counter;` declared inside your `ANodeBase` definition?

Comment: yea, of course, I'am edit question, ty.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible 12 other default-constructed `ANodeBase` instances are created without you noticing?

Comment: No, it;s created by button click + I checked object list, it contain only 1 object.

Comment: If you have a debugger, put a breakpoint next to `id_counter++;` to make sure it's only run once. Or a `cout << "new ANodeBase" << endl`.

Comment: There could be many reasons for your `ANodeBase()` to be called silently without you calling it explicitly. Maybe delegated ctors (from Derived or Base classes), maybe containers silently copying/reallocating its `ANodeBase` items (idk what UE4 uses), etc

Comment: Yeaa....It's really strange. I'm start debug from visual studio, not through attach process, but through from solution explorer->debug->start new instance and when it prepared to open ue4, it stopped 3 times and create these 13 objects. I'm newbie and it's some kind of magic for me, can you explain me how I can fix this or where I can read about that

Comment: Unreal creates a CDO (class default object)  for every UClass. It's essentially to allow you and the engine to access the default properties of any class at any time. Anything created in the constructor should be valid as part of a CDO. So really the id needs to be set elsewhere - I forget all of the init functions an AActor has but I'm sure you could find something in the header along the lines of register with world. BeginPlay might be a good option too if it's not too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found out, unreal creates CDO (class default object), which call constructor. Accordingly, I transfer my code to `BeginPlay()` and now it's work.